# Empty mbsync slave when syncing

Tags: mutt

I'm syncing my Gmail mailboxes locally with mbsync. Currently, the Gmail and local mailboxes reflect eachother 1:1, however I'd rather not store deleted mail locally.

After I have marked messages for deletion locally, how can I empty my local `Trash` mailbox and propagate those deletions to Gmail when I run my next sync?

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that hitting `d` on a message in the Trash (in mutt) copies the message to the Trash, effectively duplicating the message.

However, if I want to empty the Trash in mutt, I can hit `D.<cr>` (from within the Trash). After I sync the mailboxes, the trashed messages are deleted locally, and the deletions are propagated to the server the next time I run mbsync.